# Best practice of using HtmlTextWriter with string.Format

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, resharper

Resharping is complaning about string.Format inside HtmlTextWriter.

[image]

What will be the best practice using HtmlTextWriter with string.format?

Thank in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Write` and `WriteLine` methods on all of these classes can also take format parameters:

```
writer.Write("{0} {1}", x, y);
```

Comment: I upvoted both answers. but 'All of the Write methods can also take format parameters' makes me choose this as correct answer.

Comment: @Win, but in this case, why not just use `writer.Write(1);`?

Comment: @phoog - Good catch. This is just for a demo purpose. ;)

Answer (score 2):

The point is that you do not need to use string.Format.  You can just do this:

```
writer.Write("{0}",1);
```

See:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acsz4w2k.aspx

**HtmlTextWriter.Write Method (String, Object[])**

> Writes a formatted string that contains the text representation of an
>   object array to the output stream, along with any pending tab spacing.
>   This method uses the same semantics as the String.Format method.